# Android waiting websocket response

Tags: android, android-asynctask, websocket, java-websocket

In my application I have a websocket https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client. I send some commands to the server in my AsyncTask and showed progressBar. So I need to wait 60 seconds for response from the server after sending commands. How to do it correctly?

Comment: Please show us your code. Are you sure it's not a case with slow internet?

Comment: Hi Ruchira! Thanks for response. Yes, it is case with slow internet, so I solve problem by Thread.sleep(). How do you think it is correct way?